# passing a thrown exception from extension method to calling function in c#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, throw

I wrote an extension method for `IWebElement`.

Within this extension method, an exception might be thrown. In my case I do not want to throw the exception within the extension method but I want to pass it to the calling Method.

This is my extension method:

```
public static IWebElement FindElementByID(this IWebElement baseElement, string searchString)
{
    try
    {
        IWebElement foundElement = baseElement.FindElement(By.ID(searchString));
        return foundElement;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        new http.HttpErrorHandler().HttpError(browser.PageSource, e.Message.ToString());
        throw new NoSuchElementException(e.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

This is some example code that calls the extension:

```
/// <summary>
/// This function fetches paymant data from opened Loan
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static (int payedOnTime, int payedDelay, bool lastPaymentOnTime) FetchPaymentData()
{
    browser.FindElementByID("payment-tab").Click();
    BrowserOperations.WaitUntilIDIsVisible("card-tabs-content");
    var element = browser.FindElementByID("card-tabs-content");
    BrowserOperations.WaitUntilClassNameIsVisible("loan-table");
    var table = element.FindElementByClassName("loan-table");
    /* some calculation here */
}
```

On one of those Calls, (for example in the following line) an error might occur because the connection was interrupted, the website is down or whatever:

```
var element = browser.FindElementByID("card-tabs-content");
```

I want the exception to be thrown in the above line within method `FetchPaymentData` but instead the Exception is thrown within the extension method.

Before I used `throw new [...]`, I tried to just use `throw;` with the same result. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to have that exception starting from `FetchPaymentData` instead the helper? In call stack trace of your exception you should be able to see from where the helper is called and it should be good enough.

Comment: Put your `Try-catch` block in your `FetchPaymentData` and catch it there.

Comment: As @Nekeniehl has said put the try-catch in FetchPaymentData and when you catch the exception, lets call it 'e' just throw it again like this `throw e` this will cause the stack trace, to start from where you are 'rethrowing' it. Usually an undesired behaviour, but if thats what you want...

Comment: `new NoSuchElementException(e.Message.ToString());` if you pass the full exception object `e` and not just the message to the new exception you will be able to preserve both stacktraces and all other information.

Comment: So should I remove the try catch block from the Extension method and only put try/catch in `FetchPaymentData`? or should i have try-catch in both?